# How can I filter text/divs from two select options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am driving myself crazy trying to figure this out...

I would like two drop-down boxes that function to show/hide text as options are clicked on. I got this part down.

https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lcfm36/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").change(function(){
$(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
        $(".box").not(".red").hide();
        $(".red").show();
    }
    else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
        $(".box").not(".green").hide();
        $(".green").show();
    }
    else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
        $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
        $(".blue").show();
         }
         else{
             $(".box").hide();
         }
     });
 }).change();
 });
```

When both boxes are used together, I'd like it to filter similar to how it does here: http://jsfiddle.net/g5cryt31/

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('.selectSome').on('change', function() {
    showHide();
    });
});

function showHide() {
    // hide all rows
    $('.row').hide();
    // show good row only
    if ($('#select_category').val() != 'null' && $('#select_subject').val() != 'null') {
        $('#row_' + $('#select_subject').val() + '_' +     $('#select_category').val()).show();
    }
}
```

Except, nothing happens when you try to view one box at a time there. They need to both be used to filter...

So, first box "Class", would show nothing at first. Then, you select a class from the dropdown and related classes appear below.

Second box, "Subject" would show nothing at first. Then, you select a Subject from the dropdown and related subjects appear below.

BUT when both are used together (I guess this would require a submit button?) they filter out similar to the second jsfiddle I posted.

Comment: But I already see an improvement to your condition in your second script : `(($('#select_category').val() != 'null') && ($('#select_subject').val() != 'null'))`. More parenthesis...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you saying you want it to only show rows matching both selects, or show rows matching whatever is filled in (be that either or both)?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette sorry about that, it should be saved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want,
Correct me if I'm wrong-

This will show all elements regarding class X or Subject Y. 
If they are picked together it will show only X + Y.

This will do what you what:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('.selectSome').on('change', function() {
        showHide();
    });
});

function showHide() {
  // hide all rows
  $('.row').hide();
  // show good row only
  if ($('#select_category').val()!= 'null'){
    //class selected - check if subject seleceted
    if ($('#select_subject').val() != 'null'){
    //class and subject selected use double selector
      $('.' + $('#select_subject').val()+'.'+$('#select_category').val()).show();
    }
    else {
      //only class selected - use category selector    
      $('.' + $('#select_category').val()).show();
    }
  } 
  else
  if ($('#select_subject').val() != 'null'){
    //only subject selected without class
    $('.' + $('#select_subject').val()).show();
  }
}
```

You will have to add "c1.. s1..." classes (or data-attr) and you can loose the id's

New html for rows:

```
<div class="row s1 c1">
  Subject 1 for Class 1
</div>
<div class="row s2 c1">
  Subject 2 for Class 1
</div>
<div class="row s1 c2">
  Subject 1 for Class 2
</div>
<div class="row s2 c2">
  Subject 2 for Class 2
</div>
<div class="row s3 c2">
  Subject 3 for Class 2
</div>
<div class="row s3 c3">
  Subject 3 for Class 3
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tywy6oL/1/)

Comment: To me it opens..... also Marina's
Try this one? https://fiddle.jshell.net/hx16f9fr/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would throw out the IDs and just use data attributes. Then dynamically build the selector. Note the different definition on the row divs and the new `showHide()` function.

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $('.selectSome').on('change', function() {
    showHide();
  });
});

function showHide() {
  // hide all rows
  $('.row').hide();
  // show good rows only
  var cat = $('#select_category').val();
  var sub = $('#select_subject').val();
  var selector = "[class='row']";
  if (cat !== 'null') {
    selector += "[data-category='" + cat + "']";
  }
  if (sub !== 'null') {
    selector += "[data-subject='" + sub + "']";
  }
  $(selector).show();
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="select_class">Class:
  <select id="select_category" class="selectSome">
    <option value="null">Please select...</option>
    <option value="c1">Class 1</option>
    <option value="c2">Class 2</option>
    <option value="c3">Class 3</option>
  </select>
</label>
<br/>
<label for="select_subject">Subject:
  <select id="select_subject" class="selectSome">
    <option value="null">Please select...</option>
    <option value="s1">Subject 1</option>
    <option value="s2">Subject 2</option>
    <option value="s3">Subject 3</option>
  </select>
</label>
<hr/>
<div class="row" data-subject="s1" data-category="c1">
  Subject 1 for Class 1
</div>
<div class="row" data-subject="s2" data-category="c1">
  Subject 2 for Class 1
</div>
<div class="row" data-subject="s1" data-category="c2">
  Subject 1 for Class 2
</div>
<div class="row" data-subject="s2" data-category="c2">
  Subject 2 for Class 2
</div>
<div class="row" data-subject="s3" data-category="c2">
  Subject 3 for Class 2
</div>
<div class="row" data-subject="s3" data-category="c3">
  Subject 3 for Class 3
</div>
```